# Filling cells with sequential numbers in an Excel (2003) macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need to fill an excel column with a sequential series, in this case from -500 to 1000.  I've got a macro to do it, but it takes a lot of lines for something that seems like it should be a single function [something like FillRange(A2:A1502, -500, 1000, 1)].  But if that function exists, I can't find it.  Is the following as simple and elegant as it gets?

```
'Draw X axis scale
Cells(1, 1).Value = "mV"
Cells(2, 1).Value = -500
Cells(3, 1).Value = -499
Cells(4, 1).Value = -498

Dim selection1 As Range, selection2 As Range

Set selection1 = Sheet1.Range("A2:A4")
Set selection2 = Sheet1.Range("A2:A1502")

selection1.AutoFill Destination:=selection2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Range("A1")=-500
Range("A1").Select
Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
        Step:=1, Stop:=500, Trend:=False
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Sub FillASeries()

    With Sheet1.Range("a1")
        .Value = -500
        .AutoFill .Resize(1501, 1), xlFillSeries
    End With

End Sub
```

I don't think there's a single function, but this is as short as I can make the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is not a function.

Type -500 in A2 and type "Ctrl+Enter" (That accepts the number and selects the cell)

Then go to the "Edit" Menu --> "Fill" --> "Series"

Set the "Series in" to "Columns"

Set the "Stop Value" to 1000

Hit "OK" and you'll have the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()

    Call NumberSeriesI(Sheet1.Range("A1"), "MySeries", -1000, 500, 1)

End Sub

Sub NumberSeriesI(StartCell As Range, Header As String, FirstN As Integer, LastN As Integer, StepN As Integer)

' Integer version

    Dim i As Integer ' Value
    Dim r As Integer ' row

    StartCell.Cells(1).Value = Header ' Cells(1) makes sure it only uses the first cell of passed-in range,
                                        ' in case you pass in a multi-celled range for StartCell
    i = FirstN
    r = 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Much faster, so the screen is not refreshed until all the values in place

    For i = FirstN To LastN Step StepN
        StartCell.Cells(1).Offset(r, 0).Value = i
        i = i + StepN
        r = r + 1
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub ' NumberSeriesI
```