# Filling cells with sequential numbers in an Excel (2007) spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to fill an excel column with a sequential series, in this case from 1 to 31. As a complete noob I've no idea what a macro is so the answers on ["Filling cells with sequential numbers in an Excel (2003) macro"](https://superuser.com/questions/114097/filling-cells-with-sequential-numbers-in-an-excel-2003-macro) are indecipherable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search by clicking the round blue symbol up in the upper right with the question mark inside it. Search for insert sequence.  Basically you type something in like 1 and then 2 into the next cell.  If you have enabled the "fill handle" option, then you can move the cursor to the first cell, hold left button down and drag over the next cell and let go.  A black outline box appears around the two cells with a black small box in the bottom right.  Left click and hold on that small black box, drag to the rest of the cells and let go.  Excel makes the best guess it can about the relationship between the first two cells and then copies the relationship to the next set of cells.

Comment: Beautiful. Worked perfectly. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Excel is pretty "smart". In the first cell enter 1, the cell beneath it enter 2, then select both cells by clicking on cell 1 and drag it to cell 2 (Your cells must be stacked one on top of another in the same column). Now that they are both selected, click on the lower right-hand corner of cell 2 and drag until the desired number is shown. You can do this with days of the week, month, or even numbers as well.

[Image: 1)both cells selected 2)select bottom right corner 3)drag to desired outpout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8qnh.png)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, pick some cell and enter:

```
=ROWS($1:1)
```

then copy this cell downwards.

Comment: So by copy do you mean Ctrl+c -> Ctrl+v?

Comment: Yes................or drag the cell downwards